# unable to fetch number of rows in a particular group in solrj

Tags: solrj

i want to fetch the rows contained in an particular group..here is the code which i am using ..

```
String url = "http://localhost:8983/solr";
SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(url);
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

query.setQuery("*:*");  
query.addFilterQuery("sessionStartTime:[2013-02-01T00:00:00Z TO 2013-03-30T24:00:00Z] ");

query.add("facet", "true");
query.add("facet.field","uniqueId");
query.add("facet.field", "sessionStartTime");

query.add("group", "true");
query.add("group.field","uniqueId");

query.add("group.field","sessionStartTime");
query.add("group.main","true");
query.add("group.ngroups","true");
query.add("group.facet","true");

query.setRows(9999);

QueryResponse rs=server.query(query);

System.out.println(rs.getGroupResponse());
```

What i want is count(number of entries in each group) of each group.
    but rs.getGroupResponse() gives me null...

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested your query in the query browser of solr? E.g. pasting http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*&group=true&group.field=inStock to the url. If there is no group in the xml output, neither is in solrj.

Comment: You can also display the query built with solrj calling the to string method I think, and compare the output to what it should be in url params.